# mootools too much recursion and google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, mootools

Hi I'm having a problem with my wordpress plugin: when mootools is included no google maps is showing because of "too much recursion"
here a sample of the code:
http://www.pedemontanadelgrappa.it/fu.html

Is there a workaround for this inconvenient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always write a for in loop like this to avoid iterating over inherited member:

```
for (name in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
     //... 
    }
}
```

Comment: yep, my fault, I thought it was a simple foreach loop like php or c# :-)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem!

changed:

**for (i in points) { ... }**

to

**for (i=0; i < points.length; i++) { ... }**

and now started working.. but I can't understand the reason..

Comment: Douglas Crockford wrotes:
"...the for in statement, which can enumerate the keys stored in an object, produces all of the keys in the object’s prototype chain, not just the keys in the object itself. This causes inherited methods to appear in the enumeration, which is bad. If would have been nicer if JavaScript did not contain this flaw, but fortunately we can program around it.

In all of the A Grade browsers, we should always write for in statements in this form:

for (name in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        ...
    }
}"
http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/09/26/for-in-intrigue/